# How do I use DocumentDatabase.StartBackup() in conjunction with an RavenDB EmbeddableDocumentStore?

Tags: automation, backup, ravendb, embedded-database, document-store

I read the [Backup and Restore](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/backup-restore) doc at RavenDB website and tried it in my code.

In the doc we have:

> Initiating a backup
>
> When running in embedded mode, all you need is to call the method
>   DocumentDatabase.StartBackup().

The above line of code just won't compile with error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
'Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.StartBackup(string, bool)'
```

So I tried this just to test:

```
new DocumentDatabase(_documentStore.Configuration).
                                               StartBackup(@"~\App_Data\Backup", true);
```

The code compiles but when the app starts I get this error:

```
Could not open transactional storage: C:\Project\trunk\MyApp\App_Data\Database\Data
```

Can someone please share some working code about how can one do a full backup of an online embedded document store? Is it even possible without using RavenDB server?

My only option is doing a manual backup of the database folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leniel,
You need to use the StartBackup method on *the actual instance that you are running*.
If you are using the EmbeddableDocumentStore, you need to do:

```
 embeddableDocumentStore.DocumentDatabase.StartBackup(...);
```

Comment: Oh I see. Now I know what I was doing wrong. I had the embedded document stored variable declared as `private static IDocumentStore _documentStore;`. I then tried to find the DocumentDatabase member but I couldn't find it. I was scared... hehehe After changing it to `private static EmbeddableDocumentStore _documentStore;` it was just there. Thanks Ayende once again... you're the guy! :-)

Comment: Just a follow up Ayende: where should I call StartBackup()? I placed it after `_documentStore.Initialize();` just to test and it created the Backup folder but it contains only 2 folders: IndexDefinitions and Index. The data is not being backup...

Comment: Interesting enough after some time I saw that it just created one more folder called new with 3 files: Data, Data.pat and RVN00002.log. Is it everything I need to restore the DB in case of a failure? :)